# Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Got this two error

> Warning: include_once(Mage.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in
>   /home/XXXX/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line
>   49 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/XXXX/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Autoload/Simple.php on line
>   49

I don't know what to do. I've tried to search online but it doesn't help. Please help. I'm new in Magento. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be one of two issues.

1. Compilation mode is activated and need refreshing. Go to
   `System->Tools->Compilation` and then select the
   button `Run Compilation Process` in the top right hand corner.
2. There are some files missing or corrupted on your server. If you
       have git, or other source control, it should be easy to run a check
       to see if any files are missing.